# Looking for suggestions on how to improve my questions in order to dig myself out of a question ban

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, post-ban

I just checked that I got questions banned. It says I have reached my question limit:

[image]

Now I am not complaining about why I got question banned. I am just curious that how did it happen when I make questions very detailed.

The answers to my question (not given by me) receive fair amount of upvotes.

**I have a few questions which I would like to discuss:**

1. [Question
   1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704357/the-java-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-error-on-running-mvn)

   Now I added *all* possible details to this question and replied to every comment promptly. What else can I do to make this question better? In the end, I had to reinstall everything to make it work.
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267622/javascript-click-responding-after-one-extra-click)

   This question also I added all the details. I even added the [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) entry for helping the person reviewing the problem and added every possible detail.
3. [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289897/unable-to-set-password-of-myphpadmin)

   This question received nothing and was not even closed by the moderators. I checked all the previous answers, but none of them helped. In the end, I had to just reinstall everything and disabled the password validation.
4. [Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969881/unable-to-update-date-through-sql-query-using-hibernate)

   This question was answered by a kind man. The solution worked for me, and there wasn't a similar question to the one asked (to my knowledge). I provided every detail which I could.
5. [Question 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689847/what-does-the-following-bash-command-mean)

   The answers to this question were very detailed. Again, I added every possible detail to make this clear to users.

**I have more questions also which can be discussed, but what can I really do to improve these questions?**

Yes, I know I haven't answered any questions, but I don't think that answering questions can get you out of question ban.

Right now, I can only see my one deleted question. There might be more, but as far as I remember, I added every detail I could in those questions.

In the end, I would like to say that I am not pointing out the system or the community for this ban. Both have been very helpful in my journey of coding. I am just curious what can I really do to get out of this ban.

Comment: SO is a not a personal free help desk, instead [we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). When your questions are not only in good shape, but also turn out to be *useful to other users* and gain upvotes that way, you may remove the strict rate limiting. If not, you can ask a (hopefully useful) question every 6 months.

Comment: @JeanneDark agreed that SO is a not a personal free help desk but I try to make questions helpful for the community too, eg-[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267830/how-can-i-declare-this-anonymous-class-abstarct), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354793/can-function-pointers-be-de-referenced), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667104/re-basing-onto-a-specific-commit), even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969881/unable-to-update-date-through-sql-query-using-hibernate)

Comment: These questions all seem to be at neutral score, one is positive. AFAIK they should *not* contribute negatively to the question ban. It's probably more useful for you to ask a moderator to link you to any negatively received, deleted questions of yours.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/69249564) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/68305547) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/68288068) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/68182077) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/67816595) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/67671771) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/67614271) [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/67420558) [9](//stackoverflow.com/q/67363149) [10](//stackoverflow.com/q/66690630) [11](//stackoverflow.com/q/66687319) cc @rene (NOTE: ThunderKnight is no longer question-banned)

Comment: @CodyGray The ban was re instated after a few seconds.

Comment: Yes, you are right on the border of the threshold for the question block. You received an upvote on one of your questions about 25 minutes ago, which put you above the threshold, so you were no longer blocked. Then, 3 minutes ago, you received a downvote  on a different one of your questions, which put you below the threshold and reinstated the block. This is a bit weird, but normal. It is good news! It means you are *very close* and can easily dig yourself out of the ban by getting a few upvotes.

Comment: Wrt Q5, *What does the following bash command mean?* is a bad title and deserves a downvote regardless of the question body.

Comment: To eliminate the run-on sentences in your writing, see e.g. *[Sentence fragments & run-on sentences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNxpNCYGlsQ)* (intro only), *[Run-on sentence ❌ | How to avoid this grammar mistake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7pOki0rVi4)*, *[Run-on sentences | English Language: Grammar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLY-BteVUHQ)* (does not shame the semicolon), *[5 ways to correct run-on sentences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9CKz9EMqZs)* (the last part is hilarious!), and *[Run-ons and comma splices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fh45mhVsZrU)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Did you notice that on that first video 1/3 of the time is just chit-chat? I take that back. There's less an 1/6 of actual information in that.. :/

Comment: @CodyGray My rep has changed by almost 60 ( if I remember correctly ) still my ban isn't uplifted, kindly look into it once.

Comment: You've already received an answer giving you feedback on the quality of your questions. Please don't edit the title in a way that invalidates the answer.

Comment: I edited the question too, please check once

Comment: @cigien I feel the edited title is appropriate as now the problem is different and with continuation with the previous problem

Comment: You cannot change your answered question to ask about a different problem. (Also, why do you keep saying "once"? How many times would I check?)

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how this works. We can give you feedback on how to improve your posts, as was done previously, but we can't tell you why you happen to be banned currently. Not even mods know the exact details of the conditions.

Comment: @CodyGray OK, 'once' can be ignored but 'once' != 'myRepChange', I wanted `support` on the current status.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand. You seem to be asking a new question. Maybe you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Question 1: There are some diagnosing steps in the comments that are not edited into the question. I would add those as well and then flag for a moderator to have all comments nuked

Question 2: What you're missing is from the start an explanation what you think that code does / needs to accomplish. Code can be debugged. It helps a lot if you stepped through that code and mention relevant behavior in your question. I'm pretty sure if you did that you would have found the issue. See also *[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)*.

Question 3: *Trust me I have read most of them.* No, we won't. Share your research. It isn't that hard to link the posts you've found to the suggestions you list there and didn't work for you. What is missing there: versions / context: What version of phpMyAdmin, MySQL, and OS. Is there anything special with your MySQL install or OS? Pro tip: Include the exact error as text in your question. Don't make me transcribe the error from your screenshot. Make it easy for me. Oh, and leave out the begging in comments and expression of frustration. That has no place in a canonical knowledge base.

Question 4: That one looks reasonable enough. Maybe we can do without the sentence *Can anyone please help with this and tell me what is the best practice?*. I'm not sure how relevant this is, but does the Java version matters here? If yes, include it.

Question 5: Your post needs a better title. (thanks to [@oguzismail for that tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412303/looking-for-suggestions-on-how-to-improve-my-questions-in-order-to-dig-myself-ou/412304#comment873461_412303)) see also: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).
Move the link at the end to the intro, so we have context from the start. Don't make us guess. I would leave out emoji's, but that might be personal preference / show my age. Leave out the begging for help. You're not entitled to an answer. Our free time is not less valuable than yours.

In general: You sometimes end a sentence with a `-` where I would expect a period. At first I assumed it was a typo, but it is present in most of the questions. If that is meant to make things stand-out, familiarize yourself with [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), but don't overuse it. As for reasons questions get downvoted: You might want to read [this external site](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) as it lists the most common reasons and how to fix it.

As for your deleted questions: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is for programming questions [not to fix your Ubuntu screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288068/how-to-change-the-ui-size-of-xampp-in-linux). That also explains why you got a downvote there. We expect you've familiarized yourself with our [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  We have dedicated sites for not programming related questions. Some of those deleted questions appear to have been asked before you researched the heck out of it yourself. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for what we expect.

A question that you didn't ask doesn't need to be deleted after you got a comment with a pointer to documentation within 5 minutes of posting. All deleted questions count towards the quality ban. It is not free to delete a question. They'll hound you for the next 6 to 8.